# why are all li's and headings being collapsed/justfied/text wrapped?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, text-justify

I was experimenting with `text-align:;` and `text-justify:;`, which only appears in the `header` id, and am now getting the effect on divs I no longer want it on. I've since removed the rules entirely with no effect. This especially irritating when `li`'s are involved with syntax highlighting etc. Any idea where this is coming from?

css:

```
 #content{

    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:left;

    margin:10px 3px 3px 03x;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;

    }

    #contentspace{

    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:91%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:center;
    left:4%;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
    border-left:1px solid #000000;
    }

#header{
position:relative;
float:left;
clear:both;
background-color:#ffffff;
vertical-align:center;
text-align:center;
text-align:justify; 
text-justify:distribute;
width:91%;
left:4%;
margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-top:1px solid #000000;
border-left:1px solid #000000;
}
```

html:

the content div is loaded into the contentspace div

Comment: please could you post a fiddle in which you show the issue and explain which should be the desired result?

Comment: Show the HTML. The problem is there.

Comment: could any rule besids text-align and text-justify create this effect? i went back to my old stylesheet and things looked normal. any ideas?